# Encrypting with OpenSSL and CommonCrypto

Tags: objective-c, encryption, openssl, commoncrypto

I'm trying to ultimately encrypt a file with OpenSSL and decrypt with Objective-c CommonCrypto, but before that works I need both approaches to encrypt the same way.

This is what I have:

String to encrypt: "This is the string"

Key: "thisisthekey"

OpenSSL:

```
openssl enc -aes256 -a -e -nosalt -in InputFileWithString.txt -out OutputFile.txt thisisthekey
```

Resulting base 64 encoded string from openSSL: `HncUM4ryxSR7Rdi7Z49HPl9veOPxkk3l8GYIgorBhbk=`

Objective-c CommonCrypto:

```
+(NSString *)encryptText:(NSString *)text withKey:(NSString *)key{
    NSData *plainData = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSData *encryptedData = [plainData AES256EncryptWithKey:key];

    NSString *base64String = [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    return base64String;
}

- (NSData*)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString*)key {
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; 
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); 

    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted    = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, 
                                          buffer, bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

The resulting base 64 encoded string: `gNCs4d0GAxZHRcOtu8RVpLgN0ONKk1r5XkJ4GtL7W2I=`

As you can see, each approach is producing a different encrypted string. Any ideas how to make these both produce the same string?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/rnapier/RNOpenSSLCryptor which walks you through this and wraps it up. "thisisthekey" is not a proper key (see zaph's answer below). It is likely you actually mean to use a password, which RNOpenSSLCryptor will handle for you.

Comment: Try [OpenSSL EVP_BytesToKey CommonCrypto site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+evp_bytestokey+commoncrypto+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: This one seems very relevant: [How to decrypt data with Openssl tool encrypted with AES128 in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7535501), but the answer is not that good because it tells you to visit some blog.

Comment: Thanks guys for the input. I found a very good writeup here: https://richardwarrender.com/2016/04/encrypt-data-using-aes-and-256-bit-keys/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good working example is located here:

https://richardwarrender.com/2016/04/encrypt-data-using-aes-and-256-bit-keys/

Comment: Notes on the linked encryption: 1. Valid key sizes for AES are 128,192 & 256 bytes.
2. A random IV really needs to be used or two identical messages will be the same, even if only the first part is the same information can be determined. Create a random IV with SecRandomCopyBytes(), use it and as noted prepend it to the encrypted data.
3. The hexkey should be length validated, just padding can present interoperability issues.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use a full length key, 256-bits which is 32-bytes, do not rely on padding. `CCCrypt` expects a 32-byte key due to `kCCKeySizeAES256` but you are supplying 12 bytes and zero padding the remaining key space.
2. The default for `CCCrypt` is CBC mode but you provide a NULL IV. This will essentially give you ECB mode but it is better to speciky the option: `kCCOptionECBMode`.